# UITabbarController enable editing in more tab

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitabbarcontroller

How can I enable editing in the more tab? I can click on edit and see the items but I can't move them. Is there a option in UITabbarController?

Comment: Do you mean to modify the "more tab" on Interface Builder or on the running application?

Comment: No I mean that the user can arrange the order of the tabs.

Comment: Just a comment: don't forget to also read [this](http://www.significantpixels.com/2011/04/04/the-iphone-tab-bar/) post about tabbar usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `tabBarController.customizableViewControllers` to something, the *easiest* case would be:

```
tabBarController.customizableViewControllers = tabBarController.viewControllers;
```

after you set up the viewControllers.

Answer (score 1):

You use the UITabBarControllerDelegate protocol when you want to augment the behavior of a tab bar. In particular, you can use it to determine whether specific tabs should be selected, to perform actions after a tab is selected, or to perform actions before or after the user customizes the order of the tabs. After implementing these methods in your custom object, you should then assign that object to the delegate property of the corresponding UITabBarController object.

First of all define outlets in the app delegate and attach them on Interface Builder, i assume you know how to do this:

```
IBOutlet UITabBarItem *tabBarItem1;
IBOutlet UITabBarItem *tabBarItem2;
IBOutlet UITabBarItem *tabBarItem3;
IBOutlet UITabBarItem *tabBarItem4;
```

Then your class, probably the view controller must be UITabBarControllerDelegate and use the following hook:

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController willEndCustomizingViewControllers:(NSArray *)viewControllers changed:(BOOL)changed
```

Hope that helps !

Comment: My problem is that the user is not able to move an item.

Comment: `tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray array]; // your VCs
tabBarController.customizableViewControllers = tabBarController.viewControllers; // all VCs can be rearranged by the user` 
Check this tutorial https://github.com/erica/iphone-3.0-cookbook-/tree/master/C05-ViewControllers/07-Persistent%20Tab%20Bars